# What physical properties can't be predicted based on index of refraction?

Tags: thermodynamics, optics, condensed-matter, spectroscopy, many-body

If I tell you the real and imaginary parts of the index of refraction for all frequencies, name a property that can't be predicted based on that information.

If you're assuming this is a gas, specify your answers to properties measured in gases. Likewise for solid, etc.

edit: I see my question is not a good fit for this site: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

My apologies!

Comment: This seems to be a riddle; we usually deal with questions.

Answer (score 1):

For a gas:

Density

Nuclear half-life of the components

Viscosity

Temperature of liquefaction

Specific heat

Speed of sound

Rayleigh scattering coefficient

Comment: Given real and imaginary parts at all frequencies you probably can deduce the color... Why do you say you couldn't?

Comment: @Floris - Index of refraction is not related to absorption. So color is not related.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast It most certainly is.

Comment: The **imaginary part** of the refractive index is very much related to absorption I thought.

Comment: @Floris - You're right. My brain fart. I've edited.

Answer (score 1):

Index of refraction and the extinction coefficient are related to real and imaginary parts of dielectric function via a simple functions.

Empirical real and imaginary parts of a dielectric function (or Lorentz oscillator fits to them) are usually used when simulating macroscopic Maxwell equations. So, what is missing (assuming you do not mean the trivial, non-response releated things already answered), is the microscopic (quantum) description of local fields. See my answer here for more details: [When exactly do we substitute $\epsilon_0 \rightarrow \epsilon$ and $\mu_o \rightarrow \mu $?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/247661/when-exactly-do-we-substitute-epsilon-0-rightarrow-epsilon-and-mu-o-righ/247679#247679)

As an example, quasi-static approximation to Maxwell equations predicts identical absorption per volume unit for all sizes nano spheres of a particular material (defined with its frequency dependent wave function). In reality, the response depends on the size of the particle. In this picture is the absorption spectrum, as predicted by frequency dependent dielectric function (dashed black line), compared to quantum mechanical simulations of metallic clusters of different sizes (solid colored lines).

[image: http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.91.115431]

Comment: This is really an extended comment on another answer, but very good nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Take the **fluorescence** properties of a material for example. You cannot predict the time decay properties of the material subject to illumination just by knowing the refractive indexes.